# Why is this map reduce query failing for the case when there is a single document under a given key?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called `inbound_pos` whose documents have a key called `lines`. An example is as follows:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("537e16cf8be10a5e7e000008"),
   "cdt": ISODate("2014-05-22T15:25:03.379Z"),
   "comments": [
     [

    ] 
  ],
   "cust_shipto_id": "103",
   "doc_dt": "20140522",
   "isa_control_id": "000030456",
   "kind": "edi",
   "lines": [
     {
       "linenumber": "1",
       "net_qty": NumberInt(10),
       "uom": "EA",
       "unitcost": 10.04,
       "v_nmbr": "005-2964",
       "tm_desc": "NA" 
    },
     {
       "linenumber": "2",
       "net_qty": NumberInt(10),
       "uom": "EA",
       "unitcost": 13.59,
       "v_nmbr": "005-2966",
       "tm_desc": "NA" 
    },
     {
       "linenumber": "3",
       "net_qty": NumberInt(6),
       "uom": "BX",
       "unitcost": 18.36,
       "v_nmbr": "2201254",
       "tm_desc": "LANTISEPTIC" 
    } 
  ]
}
```

In each of the objects that make up the `lines` array, the `v_nmbr`, `net_qty`, and `unitcost` keys indicate the specific item being purchased, the quantity purchased of that item, and the unit price of that item, respectively.

What I am trying to do is get the total amount spent per `v_nmbr` across all documents in the collection. The map-reduce query is below:

```
db.inbound_pos.mapReduce(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<this.lines.length; i++) {
      emit(this.lines[i].v_nmbr, this.lines[i])
    }
}, function(key, values) {
    var totalExpenses = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      totalExpenses += values[i].unitcost * values[i].net_qty
    }
    return totalExpenses
}, {
    out: "total_expenses_per_item"
})
```

This query produces the total amount correctly for all items that have been purchased more than once, but fails for items that have only been purchased once.

Here are some example outputs:

Successful 
(item was purchased 20 times)

```
{
   "_id": "005-BUHW2076HRF",
   "value": 2366.4 
}
```

(item was purchased 2 times):

```
{
   "_id": "P54072",
   "value": 29.13 
}
```

Failed (item was purchased only once):

```
{
   "_id": "OTC11780",
   "value": {
     "linenumber": "1",
     "v_nmbr": "OTC11780",
     "net_qty": NumberInt(5),
     "unitcost": 13.68,
     "uom": "BT",
     "tm_desc": "VITAMIN E 1000 IU SOFTGEL 100/BTL" 
  } 
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, as well as an explanation if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.inbound_pos.mapReduce(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<this.lines.length; i++) {
        emit(this.lines[i].v_nmbr, this.lines[i])
    }
}, function(key, values) {
    var totalExpenses = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        totalExpenses += values[i].unitcost * values[i].net_qty
    }
    return totalExpenses
}, {
    finalize: function(key,reducedValue) {
        if (typeof reducedValue.linenumber != 'undefined') {
            return reducedValue.unitcost;
        } else {
            return reducedValue;
        }
    },
    out: "total_expenses_per_item"
});
```

The reason yours didn't work is map reduce doesn't get to the reduce phase if there is only one value, in those cases you can use the finalize function to return only the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/): MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a single value. It just returns mapped value as the result.

But MongoDB will call the finalize function for the single mapped value anyway, so you can modify result there.

The best solution is to follow this rule: The type of the return object from reduce function must be identical to the type of the value emitted by the map function.

In your case I would do this map-reduce in such way:

```
db.inbound_pos.mapReduce(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<this.lines.length; i++) {
      emit(this.lines[i].v_nmbr, this.lines[i].unitcost * this.lines[i].net_qty)
    }
}, function(key, values) {
    var totalExpenses = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      totalExpenses += values[i]
    }
    return totalExpenses
}, {
    out: "total_expenses_per_item"
})
```